# How to pass datalist's data-value in onchange function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onchange, datalist

I have a datalist with "values" and "data-values". I've managed to display only values (Auckland, Bangkok) in a select. That works as needed.

But I need to pass "data-value" to another input at the moment when option (select) is changed.

I have almost zero programming skills. I have tried to ad ´attr("data-value")´ and ´$(this).data("id")´ to my code, but it doesnt work. Another input is either empty, or "undefined" is displayed, when I change value from datalist.

```
<input list="shop_ids" id="listshops" name="shop_id" onchange="this.form.f_shop_hidden.value=this.form.shop_id.value" />

<datalist id="shop_ids">
<option data-value="1" value="Auckland"></option>
<option data-value="2" value="Bangkok"></option>
<option data-value="3" value="Sydney"></option>
</datalist>

<!-- Text field, where data-value should be displayed -->
<input type="text" name="f_shop_hidden" id="f_shop_hidden">
```

Once I click on a datalist and select Auckland, "Auckland" (value) is displayed in "f_shop_hidden" input. I need to display number "1" there (data-value).

I have been trying to crack this nut the whole week. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: Yes, I do. Actually this code is used within Wordpress add post page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const select = this.form.shop_id;
const dataValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].dataset.value;
console.log(dataValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```js
$('#listshops').on('input', function() {
        const value = $(this).val();
        const data_value = $('#shop_ids [value="' + value + '"]').data('value');
        document.getElementById("f_shop_hidden").value = data_value;
      });
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
  <input list="shop_ids" id="listshops" name="shop_id"/>

  <datalist id="shop_ids">
  <option data-value="1" value="Auckland"></option>
  <option data-value="2" value="Bangkok"></option>
  <option data-value="3" value="Sydney"></option>
  </datalist>

  <!-- Text field, where data-value should be displayed -->
  <input type="text" name="f_shop_hidden" id="f_shop_hidden">
```

I edited the answer for data list.

Comment: The thing is, I dont have a <select> in my code. I have a <datalist> and <option>. I tried your code and it didnt worked. :(

Answer (score 0):

Call a JavaScript function when input Changes. There you could access the data list id and then assign to the textbox.

```
<!-- HTML Part -->

<input list="shop_ids" id="listshops" name="shop_id" onchange="idDisplay();" />

<datalist id="shop_ids">
<option data-value="1" value="Auckland"></option>
<option data-value="2" value="Bangkok"></option>
<option data-value="3" value="Sydney"></option>
</datalist>

<!-- Text field, where data-value should be displayed -->
<input type="text" name="f_shop_hidden" id="f_shop_hidden"> 

<!-- JAVASCRIPT Part -->

<script>

function idDisplay()
{
    var element_input = document.getElementById('listshops');
    var element_datalist = document.getElementById('shop_ids');
    var opSelected = element_datalist.querySelector(`[value="${element_input.value}"]`);
    
    var id = opSelected.getAttribute('data-value');
    document.getElementById("f_shop_hidden").value = id;// Assigns data-value to textbox
} 
</script>
```